# Google spread sheet script error

Tags: google-sheets

I made a script to return a certain value based on cell reference but its giving me an error "undefined". Mentioned below is my code:-

```
 function lol() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetOne = ss.getSheetByName("DASHBOARD");
 var sheetTwo = ss.getSheetByName("DATABASE");

 var firstCol = sheetOne.getRange("H4:H4");

 var he = sheetTwo.getRange("B2").Value;


 if (firstCol.getValue() === "OVER DUE")
 {
 sheetOne.getRange("F10").setValue(he);
 }
 }
```

I would request you to help me in this matter.

Best Regards,
Sharad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
var he = sheetTwo.getRange("B2").Value;
```

to:

```
var he = sheetTwo.getRange("B2").getValue();
```

and see if that solves it ?